# Erro no count()

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

Preciso colocar um site no ar (não fui eu quem fez o site), e preciso ajustar algumas coisas nele.

Estou enfrentando um problema em um menu dinâmico: quando estou na página home ele fica ok, porém se eu navegar pelo site acontece o seguinte erro:

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Warning Message: count():
>   Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable
>   Filename: views/layout.php Line Number: 170 Backtrace: File:
>   D:\MAMPdOis\htdocs\vandario\application\views\layout.php Line: 170
>   Function: _error_handler File:
>   D:\MAMPdOis\htdocs\vandario\application\controllers\Produto.php Line:
>   589 Function: parse File: D:\MAMPdOis\htdocs\vandario\index.php Line:
>   292 Function: require_once

Segue meu fonte:

```
$menus = $this->session->userdata('menus');
if (count($menus) > 0) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($menus); $i++) {
        if (($menus[$i]['id_pai'] == '' or $menus[$i]['id_pai'] == 0) and $menus[$i]['titulo'] != '') {
            echo '<li><a href="' . (strpos($menus[$i]['url'], '//') == true ? base_url() . 'frame?link=' . $c->encrypt_decrypt('encrypt', $menus[$i]['url']) : base_url() . 'index.php/' . $menus[$i]['url']) . '"><i class="fa fa-home"></i><span>' . $menus[$i]['titulo'] . '</span></a>';
            for ($a = 0; $a < count($menus); $a++) {
                if ($a == 0) {
                    echo '<ul>';
                }
                if ($menus[$a]['id_pai'] == $menus[$i]['id']) {
                    if ($menus[$a]['titulo'] == 'Simuladores de Cálculos') {
                        echo '<li><a target="_blank" href="' . $menus[$a]['url'] . '">' . $menus[$a]['titulo'] . '</a>';
                    } else {
                        echo '<li><a href="' . (strpos($menus[$a]['url'], '//') == true ? base_url() . 'frame?link=' . $c->encrypt_decrypt('encrypt', $menus[$a]['url']) : base_url() . 'index.php/' . $menus[$a]['url']) . '">' . $menus[$a]['titulo'] . '</a>';
                    }
                    for ($b = 0; $b < count($menus); $b++) {
                        if ($b == 0) {
                            echo '<ul>';
                        }
                        if ($menus[$b]['id_pai'] == $menus[$a]['id']) {
                            echo '<li>' . $menus[$b]['titulo'] . '</li>';
                            echo '<li><a href="' . (strpos($menus[$b]['url'], '//') == true ? base_url() . 'frame?link=' . $c->encrypt_decrypt('encrypt', $menus[$b]['url']) : base_url() . 'index.php/' . $menus[$b]['url']) . 'index.php/">' . $menus[$b]['titulo'] . '</a></li>';
                        }
                        if ($b == count($menus) - 1) {
                            echo '</ul>';
                        }
                    }


                    echo '</li>';
                }
                if ($a == count($menus) - 1) {
                    echo '</ul>';
                }
            }

            echo '</li>';
        }
    }
}
```

Outro local que acontece o mesmo erro é esse:

```
<?php
$redes = $this->session->userdata('redes');
if(count($redes) > 0){
    for($i=0; $i<count($redes);$i++){
        echo '<li class="skew-25"><a href="'.$redes[$i]['url'].'" target="_blank" data-title="'.$redes[$i]['titulo'].'" data-tooltip="true"><span class="fa '.$redes[$i]['class'].' skew25"></span></a></li>';
    }
} 
?>
```

Acho que ele é mais fácil de ler e se resolver um acho que dá pra ajeitar o outro.

Answer (score 1):

Para resolver o erro poderia verificar é contável, usando [`is_contable`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.is-countable.php) (ou `is_array`, se não estiver no PHP 7.3)( antes de usar  `count()`, então seria algo como:

```
if (is_countable($redes) && count($redes) > 0) {
}
```

Isso iria remover o *warning*, porque somente iria usar o `count()` quando o `$redes` fosse [`is_contable`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.is-countable.php).

Mas, você teria que ver o que está sendo adicionado no `$redes` que faz não ser contável. Por exemplo, se o `$this->session->userdata->redes` for uma *string* ele não será contável, mas deve investigar onde está sendo adicionado uma *string* e não uma *array*.

Comment: tentei aqui e não deu, parece ser algo relacionado a session no codeigniter